# Delete subfolder and keeping up parent folder

Tags: find, rm

I need to delete folderx which are not accessed for seven days, easily I can do it with next:

```
find /path/folder -type d -mtime +7 |xargs rm -rf
```

The probelm is when I have subfolder marked for deletion and parent folder is not, I can do it with with adding `maxdepth 1`, but actually it is not solution from top to bottom, I need solution to define from bottom to top where I have

```
folder 1 (accesed 8 days ago)
-> folder 2 (accessed 8 days ago)
-> folder 3 (accessed 4 days ago),
```

With maxdepth 1 it will delete first two and also folder 3 which I don't want do do it.

So actually I need some solution from bottom to top for this. If subfolder is marked for deletion and parent is not etc.

Comment: Are you looking for [`tmpreaper`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/tmpreaper)/[`tmpwatch`](https://fedorahosted.org/tmpwatch/)?

Comment: use recursion instead of `find`

Comment: i can not use tmpreaper and tmpwatch, @RSFalcon7 what actually you meant when you sad recursion insted of find ?

Comment: create a function e.g. that deletes the current dir only if for all subdirs were not accessed within 7 days or it is empty, the return value is a key here, since you pass info using bottom-up approach

Comment: i tried but without success can you help me pls @RSFalcon7

Comment: @vladeli I won't be able to look at this any time soon, but [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/recursionsct.html) are some examples of recursion, you just need to adapt to manipulate your directories ;)

Comment: @vladeli why can't you use tmpreaper/tmpwatch? Is there some way they don't meet your requirements?

Comment: i dont have permissions to use them or to install anything in my sudo list i have find and rm -rf for this

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/folder -type d -ctime +7 | xargs rm -rf
```

`ctime +7` only consider the ones with modification time older than 7 days